# Angular 9 - Exiting an Input Box is Emitting an Unrelated Event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eventemitter, angular-event-emitter

I have a child component that I am passing data from and displaying in the parent component. The parent component passes it a number and an eventEmitter to allow the parent to display the data updated by the child component.

**Parent Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    {{ myCount }}
    <app-message-creator
      (change)="countChange($event)"
      [count]="myCount"
      >
    </app-message-creator>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'App2';
  myCount: number = 0;

  newMessage: string = "";

  constructor() { }

  countChange(event) {
      this.myCount = event;
  }
}
```

**Child Component** *message-creator*

```
import { Component, Output, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message-creator',
  template: `
    <p>message-creator works!</p>
    <button (click)="increment()">+</button>
    <button (click)="decrement()">-</button>
    <input type="text">
  `
})
export class MessageCreatorComponent {

  messageBox;

  @Input() count: number;

  @Output() change: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  increment() {
    this.count++;
    this.change.emit(this.count);
  }

  decrement() {
    this.count--;
    this.change.emit(this.count);
  }
}
```

Then I planned for the message creator component to have the user input a message and it would display in the main component. I added a `<input type=text>`, but now if I enter any text into the input box and the cursor leaves the box the `countChange` event is triggered and the passed `event` is of type `[Object Event]` and it ruins the `count` variable in the parent container.

I realize that I could put an if statement in the countChange function, but I think I am doing something wrong.

Comment: `count` - shouldn't be an input to `MessageCreatorComponent`

Comment: The problem is the name of the event: `change`. It conflicts with the native event. Change it to something like `countChange`. Also, note that you can use two-way data-binding: `[(count)]="count"`. Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7j89h

Comment: I should have known `change` would be a taken event name! Thanks @developer033, as soon as I changed the name it worked as expected, and I will look into the two-way binding that you and @Adam advised thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @developer033 pointed out in the comments the `change` event conflicts with the native change event on the text input. So simply changing the name of the event fixed the issue.